# How to filter and map a 2D IntArray into a Set using streams

Tags: arrays, kotlin, java-stream

I have a 2D `IntArray` which represent a game board where -1 means a blank space, and some value grater or equals to 0 means that cell belongs to some player. Something like below (-1 are represented by dots(.))

```
. . . . . 
1 0 . . 2
0 . 1 3 3
4 3 . . 0
```

I want to get a `Set` with the location of cells already occupied by any player. Something like this:

```
[Cell{1,0}, Cell{1,1}, ..., Cell{3,4}]
```

I know the first approach would be iterate over the 2D array:

```
val set = HashSet<Cell>();
for(row in 0 until HEIGHT){
    for (col in 0 until WIDTH){
        if(board[row][col] >= 0)
            set.add(Cell(row, col))
    }
}
```

But... is it somehow more efficient if I use streams? could it be achieved in less code and more efficiently?

```
IntStream.range(0, HEIGHT)
            .mapToObj { row -> IntStream.range(0, WIDTH)
                    .filter{ col -> board[row][col] >= 0}
                    .mapToObj { col -> Cell(row, col) } }
            .flatMap { point -> point }
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is recommended to use the Kotlin standard library and not Java streams. With the Kotlin standard library, [s1m0nw1 gave a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946951/3755692) where I'd only replace the `flatMap` with a `flatMapTo` call to avoid creating a list that is later discarded:

```
val set = HashSet<Cell>()
(0 until board.size).flatMapTo(set) { row ->
    (0 until board[row].size).filter { col ->
        board[row][col] >= 0
    }.map { col ->
        Cell(row, col)
    }
}
```

If you really need a Java8 stream solution, go with the following code:

```
fun IntRange.stream() : Stream<Int>
    = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false)

val set = (0 until board.size).stream().flatMap { row ->
    (0 until board[row].size).stream().filter { col ->
        board[row][col] >= 0
    }.map { col ->
        Cell(row, col)
    }
}.collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

As of performance, both solutions given here should be quite similar (I haven't tested it though). However, Java8 streams allow you do operations in parallel (see [`StreamSupport.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-)). This is using some thread pool that does all the magic for you. Kotlin, as far as I know, does not offer any parallel operations out of the box, but it has [Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html) that are a lot faster than Java threads - but come together with more code on your side.

Answer (score 1):

This can be made a bit more Kotlin-natural if the Java streams are replaced by ranges.

```
val cells = (0 until board.size).flatMap { row ->
    (0 until board[row].size)
            .filter { col -> board[row][col] >= 0 }.map { Cell(row, it) }
}.toSet()
```